# Partial fractions decomposition and polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(z) = a_n z^n + ... + a_0 $ be complex polynomial. we can write

$$ f(z) = \prod_{j=1}^k (z-r_j)^{m_j} $$

Why does it follow that

$$ \frac{ f'(z)}{f(z)} = \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{m_j}{z-r_j} $$

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with $$f(z) = \prod_{j=1}^k (z-r_j)^{m_j}$$ take the logarithms of both sides; so $$\log\Big(f(z)\Big)=\sum_{j=1}^k \log\Big((z-r_j)^{m_j}\Big)=\sum_{j=1}^km_j\log(z-r_j)$$ and now compute the derivatives to get the result.

This is just the application of logarithmic differentiation.